# Why are there champion trains in low-level maps?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I recently started playing GW2 again and noticed that there are champion trains in low-level maps like Queensdale. A champion train seems to be a semi-organized group of people killing the champions in a given rotation. Those trains will cycle the rotation many hours.

However, shouldn't diminished returns make such behaviour less profitable? Or is there something new that you can get from champions only (haven't played since May).

Comment: Never got really into GW but it looks like they are just farming the extremely rare drops. There are several reasons to do this, little profit and faster leveling with a new character are on the low end. But having a good equipped low level character is good for PvP and it looks cool. There was a name for those good equipped low level characters back int he day when i was playing mmo's but i forgot.

Isn't there a website where you can see the droprates of enemies? There are probably some 0.01% drop items which "normal" people never get :D

Comment: @MennoGouw This is incorrect, for GW2 at least. GW1 sounds more like your description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the champions are being farmed for their [loot bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_loot_bag), which have been added [in August](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Queen%27s_Jubilee). The Queensdale rotation seems to be one of the most-efficient, since the champions are quite easy and the map also provides the Shadow Behemoth for a additional bonus.

Comment: That is correct. A high level player in a low level map has a chance to get a Rare or Exotic quality item that a low level player wouldn't see. I think players doing champion trains are mostly "farming" for upper tier crafting materials, rare weapon skins, and scrolls of knowledge (1 skill point).

Comment: Most people who just want the loot do the champ train in Frostgorge. Since it's a level 80 zone, you're guaranteed exotic loot bags, unlike in Queensdale. However, most of the champs have associated events in Queensdale, so that train is better if you're looking for experience (and skillpoints) or karma.

Answer (score 4):

This is also a quick solution to complete your monthly "Champion slayer" achievement. As it is the case in [October 2013](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Monthly).

Comment: +1: Good call, however, the people should have killed >60 champions by now and the trains keeps rolling rolling rolling…

Comment: @Zeta It's not always the same players doing it, though. Many of the participants are in it for the monthly achievement.